# Why is rectangle not rendering to screen

Tags: java, swing, graphics

```
public class Rec extends JFrame {    
   public Rec (){       
   JFrame jframe = new JFrame();       
   jframe.setSize(500, 500);
   jframe.setVisible(true); 
 }

public void render (Graphics g){
   g.setColor(Color.red);
   g.fillRect(0,0,50,50);          
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rec frame = new Rec();
    frame.render(g);        
     }    
  }
```

Why does this not work? I am aware I may need a `paintComponent`, if so how would I go about doing this? Any help would be great, Thank You!

Comment: Where do you define `g` and assign it a value?

Comment: Because, this is not his painting is done. Instead, start with a JPanel, override it's paintComponent method (calling super.paintComponent) and do your custom painting in there

Comment: `reneder()` as method name instead of `render()`. Maybe that.

Comment: A couple thoughts: 1) Why are you extending JFrame and creating an instance of JFrame inside of it? You normally do one or another, not both. 2) You should override the paintComponent method, not (apparently) render; do not forget to call super on it. 3) Once you override paintComponent, there is no need to call it directly, just be sure your JFrame is visible. 4) Maybe you want to paint on a JPanel, and then add it to a JFrame.

Comment: @jachinte *"Maybe you want to paint on a JPanel, and then add it to a JFrame."* One of the many reasons why is because the `JPanel` actually **has** a `paintComponent` as mentioned in your points 2 & 3. OTOH `JFrame` does not! This is a good point to mention the value of `@Override` notation, since the compiler will warn us if we think we are changing a method that actually does not exist. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, I actually should have mentioned that I did not check my comment. My mistake. In my defense, it was very late for me :P

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that painting in a JFrame is not what you should be doing. It is better (in this instance) to set the contentpane as a `JPanel`, and paint inside the `JPanel`.

Take this short snippet as an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Rec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame rec = new JFrame();
                rec.setSize(50, 150);
                rec.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
                    }           
                });
                rec.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//May be this is what you are looking for.

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
// Create a copy of the passed in Graphics object
Graphics gCopy = g.create();
// Change the properties of gCopy and use it for drawing here
// Dispose the copy of the Graphics object
gCopy.dispose();
}

//or might be this

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawingCanvas extends JPanel {
public DrawingCanvas() {
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 75));
}
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
// Draw a rectangle
g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame =new JFrame("Drawing");
frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawingCanvas());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```